# downloading files from artifactory to unix using python

Tags: python, artifactory

I looked online and found sites like that:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API

but couldn't simply just figured out how to simply give the script a URL
and download the files to a giving path to a giving folder in the unix.

if anyone can just get me started it will be great.

Comment: I recommend investigating the [Jfrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory). We use it for our automated scripts, simply because its easier to debug than curl statements to a REST API endpoint which can sometimes be a bit obscure. It's then as simple a `jfrog rt dl <repository path>` once you've configured it with credentials and URL. This has the advantage of automatic retries, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Every file stored in an Artifactory repository has a static link to it. Something like

```
https://<server>/artifactory/<repository>/<path-to-file>/<file>
```

You can get the link from the UI if you browse to the file in the repository tree and copy the "URL to file".

So you can `curl` for this file (and add auth if needed) like this:

```
curl -u name:password -O https://<server>/artifactory/<repository>/<path-to-file>/<file>
```

And get `<file>` locally.

The same URL can be used by any curl library in python (or other languages).

Comment: you know what should i import to use this function? and after using the curl command in the python script the file is downloaded to where?

Comment: Look at the examples in https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/download-a-file-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
import subprocess

command = "curl -u<username>:<password> -T <target_file_path> <your_artifactory_repo/target_file>"
proc = subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```